# Reporting of VS 2010 and my issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting, reportparameter

I make a WinForms app and I use ReportViewer on my form and I design a report (`.rdlc`) for it. In my report I select my table and stored procedure and I define the parameter for my stored procedure, and in form load event of my form I write :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'testoDataSet.Table2' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
     this.Table2TableAdapter.Fill(this.testoDataSet.Table2);

     ReportParameter pa = new ReportParameter("Name", "abc");
     ReportParameter pa1 = new ReportParameter("Family", "xyz");

     reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { pa, pa1 });
     reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

     this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
 }
```

but when I run my app all records showed on my report viewer but my select query is:

```
select * 
from User 
where Name = 'abc' and Family = 'xyz';
```

What is wrong??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it solved:

```
this.Table2TableAdapter.FillByNameAndFamily(this.testoDataSet.Table2, "abc", "xyz");
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to be passing the parameters in an overloaded TableAdapter.Fill

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171905%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Also a guide [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ReportViewer.aspx?fid=341063&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2427923) for WebForms but should be similar.

Comment: sqlhelper in this code is what kind object??"thisDataSet = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(thisConnection, 
                      "ShowProductByCategory", SearchValue);
"